# What is the formal synonym of the hot weather?

Tags: synonyms, formal-language, academic-writing

Is there any substitute for the word **hot** in the following sentence?

> In recent years the weather is becoming **hotter**. In 2018, for instance,
> some areas in eastern and southern Europe baked in temperature,
> experiencing 46 degrees C.

I wonder if there is any synonym that seems more **formal** and **academic** than **"hot"**.

Comment: Usually, one talks about "extreme weather". The weather is becoming more extreme. As mentioned, you might comment on increasing temperatures. The phrase "Europe baked in temperature" doesn't sounds right to me. If you're writing more formally, you might opt to describe "...Europe set heat records, reaching 46 degrees C."

Comment: Or you could say 'Europe baked in temperatures _as high as_ 46 deg. C'. It's true that we speak of a person with fever as 'having a temperature', but in general 'temperature' on its own doesn't imply heat.

Answer (score 2):

Not really. One could rephrase to use "higher temperature" instead of "hotter" probably replacing "the weather". Perhaps something like "In recent years the world has been experiencing higher temperatures". But that is wordier and lacks the punch of the original, to no added benefit. There is nothing bad about using a simple word like "hot" even in a formal academic context. "Temperature" is already used in the next sentence where it refers to a specific measurement.